# Compare whether one group are significantly closer to real observations than other

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have two groups consisting of non-parametric estimated data of a phenomenon. I want to compare these two groups of estimations with a third group of real observations of the same phenomena. Basically, I want to check whether one group is significantly closer to the real observations than the other. After a little search, I ended up identifying Wilcoxon paired test (or Wilcoxon Signed Rank test) as my way to go, but couldn't quite figure out how to interpret its results. Since I'm a newbie to non-parametric statistics, I need a little help on how use the Wilcoxon paired test to test the hypothesis that Group A is significantly closer to real observations than Group B, for example.

I came out with two approaches:

1. Apply a Wilcoxon paired test directly between the two groups and the real observations. Therefore, the group who have the lower p-value (if < 0,05) in comparison to the real observations is significantly more different than the other at 5% of significance.
2. Calculate the absolute errors |N observed - N estimated| and perform a one-tailed Wilcoxon paired test between the two error groups to check whether the absolute errors of group A are significantly lower than group B. Therefore if p-value < 0.05 group A has significantly less errors than group B, i.e. is closer to real observations at 5% significance.

Which one of them do you consider most appropriate to test my hypothesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview.**

If you use method (1), then you will have no information
to make a direct comparison between the two methods of estimation.
It is not appropriate to interpret a larger P-value to mean
that $H_0$ is "more true."

[Under $H_0,$ P-values of exact tests
on continuous data are uniformly distributed. However, the nonparametric Wilcoxon signed rank test is based on (discrete) ranks and uses normal approximations when sample sizes are large. The
test is calibrated to have correct error probabilities for usual
significance levels (say, below 10%), but P-values should be used
for deciding whether to reject $H_0.]$

If you use method (2), then you can see how well each kind of estimate performs.

**Simulated results** for sample median vs. sample midrange of normal data
as estimates of population mean.

To illustrate, consider whether the sample median or the sample midrange is the more reliable estimate of the center $\mu$ of a sample from a normal population. [Of course, we know the sample mean has nice properties. It turns out that the median is generally better than the midrange.]

We choose normal samples of size $n = 50$ from normal populations
with means $\mu$ in $(30,60)$ and SDs $\sigma=3.$ Then we do paired
Wilcoxon (signed rank) tests to assess the properties of sample medians and midranges as estimates of $\mu.$

```
# fictitious data simulated in R
set.seed(2022)
mu = runif(50, 30, 60)  # various centers for normal samples
mean(mu)
[1] 45.16524

h = mr = numeric(50)
for(i in 1:50){
 x = rnorm(50, mu[i], 3)
 h[i] = median(x)
 mr[i] = mean(range(x)) }
mean(h); sd(h)
[1] 45.14566    # average median nearly matches avg of means
[1] 8.562685    # SD of medians slightly smaller than SD
                # of midranges
mean(mr); sd(mr)
[1] 45.19334
[1] 8.63267     # slightly larger than above.
```

A large component of the variance of medians and of midranges
is due to the variety of values of $\mu$ used in the simulation.

Method (1)

```
pv.h.mu = wilcox.test(h,mu, pair=T)$p.val; pv.h.mu
[1] 0.8620549  # Medians not significantly biased
wilcox.test(h,mu, pair=T, conf.int=T)

     Wilcoxon signed rank test 
     with continuity correction

data:  h and mu
V = 619, p-value = 0.8621
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1467199  0.1214599
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median 
   -0.01538954 

pv.mr.mu = wilcox.test(mr,mu,pair=T)$p.val; pv.mr.mu
[1] 0.6922641
wilcox.test(mr,mu, pair=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  mr and mu
V = 679, p-value = 0.6923
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Method (2). Absolute errors for the median tend to be smaller than absolute errors
for the midrange.

```
pv.d = wilcox.test(abs(h-mu),abs(mr-mu), pair=T)$p.val; pv.d
[1] 0.0003293868
wilcox.test(abs(mr-mu),abs(h-mu), pair=T, conf.int=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  abs(mr - mu) and abs(h - mu)
V = 1010, p-value = 0.0003294
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1554304 0.5230677
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median 
     0.3184359 

mean(abs(mr-mu));  sd(abs(h-mu))
[1] 0.7289042
[1] 0.3220564
```

Paring of sample medians with population means and of sample midranges with population means allows
us to focus on the smaller absolute errors for medians.